# A good way to implement background asynchronous data sync without using websockets

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs, websocket

I have an Angular app, that's a client of a RESTful API, unfortunately, we didn't implement
a Web - socket driven server push.

So what I am asking for basically is a hack, with minimal to none server side implementation.

As a first step, I'm adding a 'refresh data' button, but if also want to make a seamless data refresh in the Background, say every 5 minutes, for this purpose I'll have to attach a time stamp to each data set received from the server, or just run the sync \ refersh data procedure within a setInterval function(do not like).

Also there is the point, that the use could be doing anything while I am running this seamless refresh procedure, so any actions done by the user during the refresh need be placed in a queue.

Or perhaps, I should store the local data, and the newly fetched data, and the local data separately, and then on the next time that there are no AJAX request pending(using an interceptor to know when that time is), merge both objects with $.extend() or similar?.

Any better way of doing that?.

I am sorry for the general question, but I didn't implement anything similar so far, and I don't want to make it messy \ practice any bad practices.

```
(function(){
    angular.module('dataSync', ['myApp.services', 'urlConfig']).
    service('syncService', function($timeout, $rootScope, jobsService, companyService, authService, REFRESH_RATE){
        var _root = this;
        _root.syncProgress = false;
        _root.syncApplicants = null;
        _root.syncPositions = null;
        _root.syncCompany = null;
        _root.filters = {};
        _root.syncFn = function(){
            _root.filters = jobsService.getApplicantFilters();
            _root.filters.company = _root.filters.company || authService.getCompanyId();

            companyService.getCompany(_root.filters.company, true).then(function(data){
                _root.syncCompany = data.data;
            },
            function(data){
                console.log('background company fetching has failed');
            });

            jobsService.fetchApplicants(_root.filters).then(function(data){
                _root.syncApplicants = data.data;
            },
            function(data){
                console.log('background applicant fetching has failed');
            });

            jobsService.getCompanyJobs(_root.filters.company).then(function(data){
                _root.syncPositions = data.data;
            },
            function(data){
                console.log('background job fetching has failed');
            });

            _root.syncRef = $timeout(_root.syncFn, REFRESH_RATE);
        }
        // var myIntervalFunction = function() {
        _root.syncRef = $timeout(function() {
            _root.syncFn();
        }, REFRESH_RATE);
        // };
        return{
            performSyncMerge: function(){
                if(_root.syncProgress)
                    return;
                if(!_root.syncApplicants || !_root.syncPositions  || !_root.filters.company || !_root.syncCompany)
                    return;
                _root.syncProgress = true;

                var localComapny = companyService.getCompanyData(_root.filters.company);
                var mergedCompany = localComapny && localComapny.length ? $.extend(localComapny, _root.syncCompany) : _root.syncCompany;
                companyService.setCompany(mergedCompany);


                jobsService.refreshCompanyData(_root.filters.company, {'data':mergedCompany});

                var localApplicants = jobsService.getApplicants();
                var mergedApplicants = localApplicants && localApplicants.length ? $.extend(localApplicants, _root.syncApplicants) : _root.syncApplicants;
                jobsService.setApplicants(mergedApplicants);

                var localPositions = jobsService.getJobs(_root.filters.company);
                var mergedPositions = localPositions && localPositions.length ? $.extend(localPositions, _root.syncPositions) : _root.syncPositions;
                jobsService.setJobs(mergedPositions, _root.filters.company);
                if(!$rootScope.$$phase){
                    $rootScope.$digest();
                }
                _root.syncProgress = false;
                _root.syncApplicants = null;
                _root.syncPositions = null;
                _root.syncCompany = null;
                _root.filters = {}; 
                _root.syncProgress = false;
            }
        }
    });
})();
```

---

```
/*In the run function:*/
var $http,
                interceptor = ['$q', '$injector', '$rootScope', function ($q, $injector, $rootScope) {
                    var error;

                    function success(response) {
                        // get $http via $injector because of circular dependency problem
                        $http = $http || $injector.get('$http');
                        var $timeout = $injector.get('$timeout');
                        var $rootScope = $injector.get('$rootScope');
                        var syncService = $injector.get('syncService');
                        if($http.pendingRequests.length < 1) {
                            $timeout(function(){
                                if($http.pendingRequests.length < 1){
                                    $rootScope.htmlReady();
                                    $rootScope.$broadcast('loadMenu', []);//This is a safety measue to assure that the menu is indeed loaded
                                    $rootScope.$broadcast('contentLoaded', []);
                                    syncService.performSyncMerge();
                                }
                            }, 700);
                        }
                        return response;
                    }

                    function error(response) {
                        var $location = $location || $injector.get("$location");
                        var authService = authService || $injector.get("authService");
                        // var $rootScope = $rootScope || $injector.get("$rootScope");
                        // console.log(response);
                        if(response.status + '' == '401' && response.config.url.indexOf('/users/me') == -1){
                            authService.setRole('guest');
                            if($location.path() != '/login' && $location.path() != '/logout')
                                authService.setNextPath($location.path());
                            authService.setRole('guest');
                            // $rootScope.$broadcast('logout');
                            $rootScope.$broadcast('reloadMenu');
                            $location.path('/login');   
                        }
                        return $q.reject(response); 
                    }

                    return function (promise) {
                        return promise.then(success, error);
                    }
                }];

            $httpProvider.responseInterceptors.push(interceptor);
```

Comment: Without Web Socket, you need to choose: Continuous polling (using setInterval) or Long polling (http://techoctave.com/c7/posts/60-simple-long-polling-example-with-javascript-and-jquery)

Comment: Another question:
Once I've stored the merged data in in the services, is it better to broadcast a custom event to handle the loading of the data from the services into the controllers, or just call $rootScope.digest() if there is no $$phase?

Comment: Is it possible to animate the changes somehow?

Comment: q1 - Could you give a example of what are you trying to do?

q2- I don't know what are you trying to do, maybe you can use angular.js framework or knockout js lib.